# this code could garbage collecting?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I have some question about Java garbage collection.

Below is the code of some test class

```
public class ChildMaker{
  public Child createChild(){
      Child c = new Child();
      return c;
  }
}
```

And the actual test I'm performing

```
public class TestChildMaker{
    public getChild(){
        ChildMaker maker = new ChildMaker();
        Child c = maker.createChild();
        ....
    }        
}
```

I wonder if the `ChildMaker`instance can be garbage collected. Can it ?

Comment: The class or the object?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis : I edited it considering that garbage collecting a class makes no sense.

Comment: @Dici (Well, it does. It's just very uncommon.)

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I'm sorry then, I didn't know about it !

Comment: Unless you're doing some pretty weird stuff, you don't have to worry about how garbage collection works.  Your objects will get "collected" when they are no longer needed, without any action on your part.

Comment: @shinjw Actually it is far more likely that nothing is garbage-collected at all in that case.

Answer (score 2):

The Java garbage collector is sophisticated, and likes to work fairly autonomously. You can't force it to garbage collect anything, and you can only give it an indication of when it might like to garbage collect.

Any object to which a reference is still held in your program (strictly: by any thread that could still run) cannot be garbage collected. Anything else could be.

I think you're asking whether the `ChildMaker` instance can be garbage collected while the `Child` is still referenced. Strictly speaking such a position does not exist in the code that you provided. The answer is yes; if the `ChildMaker` is unreferenced then it can be garbage collected even if the `Child` is still referenced, because the `Child` does not hold a reference to the `ChildMaker`.

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on what happens

```
public getChild(){
    ChildMaker maker = new ChildMaker();
    Child c = maker.createChild();
    .... // here <-------- 
}
```

If the variable `maker` is reused, the object it references is reachable and can therefore not be garbage collected. If `maker` is not reused, then the object is no longer reachable and can therefore be garbage collected.

The [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.6.1) states

> A reachable object is any object that can be accessed in any potential
>   continuing computation from any live thread.